# SQL pagination - Find page matching a criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

Imagine this table

```
+---------+-------------+-----+
| id      | name        | seq |
+---------+-------------+-----+
|       1 | Name1       |   5 |
|       2 | Name2       |   4 |
|       3 | Name3       |   2 |
|       4 | Name4       |   1 |
|       5 | Name5       |   3 |
...
| 1000000 | Name1000000 | 999 |
+---------+-------------+-----+
```

Let's paginate it

```
SELECT id, name, seq FROM my_table ORDER BY seq LIMIT 5 OFFSET {x};
```

Now I'd like to show the page where `id = 500`.

So the expected would be

```
+-----+---------+-----+
| id  | name    | seq |
+-----+---------+-----+
| 651 | Name651 | 123 |
|  97 | Name97  | 124 |
| 198 | Name198 | 125 |
| 480 | Name480 | 126 |
| 500 | Name500 | 127 | <- Matching row here
+-----+---------+-----+
```

**Is it possible to display the corresponding page

by keeping the performance advantage of the pagination ?**

---

Precision: I'm using PostgreSQL and actually paginating a query

Comment: Are there gaps in the `id`?

Comment: There is no `order by` clause in your query. Therefore the `id = 500` can be in any page.

Comment: Now there is. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 0):

Why not just limit results by `id` directly:

```
SELECT id, name FROM my_table WHERE id <= 500 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sequence` has no gaps and starts at 1:

```
select id, name, seq
from my_table
order by seq
limit 5
offset (
    select (seq - 1) / 5 * 5
    from my_table
    where id = 500
);
```